# How widely accepted is the semi-parliamentary classification of executive-legislative relations that was espoused in Ganghof, 2018?

Tags: political-theory, political-system

In [Ganghof, 2018](https://ejpr.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/1475-6765.12224), the author argues that Australia and Japan both have a newly classified system of government that he dubbed the 'semi-parliamentary system'. In it, the legislative branch is split into two equally legitimate parts (i.e. they're both directly elected by the people)—one part has the ability to cast no confidence votes and the other does not. The executive is solely comprised of the ministers that are accountable to the one chamber that has the ability to cast no confidence votes.

My question is, how widely accepted is this classification? I know that older literature used the term to refer to Israel 1996-2001, as in it the prime minister was directly elected, but how widely accepted is this new classification? Like, what percentage of political science experts accept it as a legitimate classification?

Comment: It obviously proposes new terminology and is a recent paper... Google Scholar finds some 19 citations, but some are self-citations in subsequent papers of Ganghof.

Answer (score 2):

No, as I haven’t heard this typology applied to Australia before.

At first reading it seems strange to me that the Commonwealth of Australia should be described as *semi*-parliamentary when the Constitution is so focussed on the central if not supreme role of the Parliament. Responsible government (with an executive drawn from both Houses of the Parliament and continuously accountable to it) is a key feature. The Senate and its committees play such a big role in holding the executive to account and many members of the government are also senators. It’s lack of support from a hostile Senate that often leads us to elections. I fail to understand the logic behind downplaying the “parliamentary” nature of the government merely because the Senate is democratically elected and yet can’t *directly* dismiss the executive government like the House of Representatives can. The contrast with the Israeli Constitution is stark as they have a Parliament but also have an elected executive President - hence “semi-parliamentary“ seems to fit.

Further reading tells me that he uses the term because of a parallel he draws between the Australian system of government and the basis for the term semi-presidential:

> ...in semi‐parliamentarism both parts of the assembly (most commonly:
>   both houses) are legitimised though direct election, but the prime
>   minister and his or her cabinet are dependent on the confidence of
>   only one of them. Both hybrids establish a partial dependence of the
>   executive on the assembly's confidence: either only a part of the
>   executive is dependent on confidence (semi‐presidentialism), or only a
>   part of the assembly needs to provide this confidence
>   (semi‐parliamentarism).

(Please also refer to his table that is the basis for the typology.) To me this seems a flimsy and illogical basis for the term “semi-parliamentary” as he uses it in his typology. I don’t question the fittingness of the typology itself just use of the term “semi-parliamentary”.

Having executive government only *partly* in the hands of a president is logically called *semi*-presidential. But no such logical case can be drawn for semi-parliamentary.

For those reasons I suspect the typology will not be widely used in Australia, or at least its use will not go beyond highly technical academic use, and thus is not “widely accepted” in terms of your question.

Answer (score -1):

Not widely accepted at all, as both nations are Constitutional Monarchies.  Japan's head of State is the Emperor of Japan (note: "Imperial Japan" or "Japanese Empire" strictly refer to the period of the Meiji Restoration (1868?) up until V-J Day (1945), a time period where the Emperor had arguably the most political power at any point in history.  In fact, for the vast period of documented history, the Emperor of Japan had very little in the way of actual authority and typically the "head of government" was either a military commander (the Shogunate, The military Occupation under General MacArthur) or the Prime Minister of the Diet (present period).).

The Head of State of Austrailia is Queen Elizabeth II (the same one who is Queen of the UK... as well as Canada, New Zealand, and some small independent island nations that were formally colonies of Great Britain).   The day to day functions of the Monarch in all nations that still recognize her as the Head of State are performed by the "Governor General" of that nation, which is determined by each nation's constitution (except New Zealand, which does not have a codified constitution).   Most of the formal political powers of Govenor Generals are quite limited and they are not executives at all (in less serious answers, I like to refer to their primary duty as "Keep the Throne Warm for the Queen".  Mostly when I'm with citizens of the nation and feel like getting my republican on (not a political party... just opposition to monarchs).

Germany is a Parlimentary Republic in that the elected head of state (President of Germany) has very little in the way of actual political power, much in the way that the Queen of England (and all that other stuff) does... the Germans merely have the ability to put the next one in office before the current one dies.

France is a Semi-Presidential Republic due to the fact that the President of France does have executive powers when his/her party makes the majority in the legislature... but is only Head of State if this is not the case (and it rarely is).

Comment: What does being constitutional monarchies (which is not a proper noun, by the way, no need to capitalize it) have to do with whether they're semi-parliamentary or not? There's no requirement for the head of state to be republican in nature in the semi-parliamentary model. What does Germany have to do with anything? It's not mentioned in the question and has nothing to do with the semi-parliamentary model.

Comment: Germany is classified as a "Parliamentary System" where as France is "Semi-Presidential".   Japan is specifically a parliamentary model, but since it's head of state is a monarch it's a constitutional monarchy.   Australia's system is odd ball mix of American Legislature and British Legislature (the lower house operates similar to British  parliament while the upper house acts like the American Senate (the difference is the Canadian Senate and House of Lords cannot introduce bills to the legislature.  The U.S. and Aussie senates cannot introduce money bills to the legislatures).+

Comment: I'm not familiar with Portugal's model, but considering that Europe favors semi-presidential systems to Presidential Systems favored by the Americas.

Comment: I am wondering if semi-parliamentary system you're describing is when Bicameral legislatures have unequal powers between the houses, which may work here but only in so far as a classification of legislatures, where most government classification systems classify the distribution of legislative powers, executive powers among the legislature, head of state, and head of government.

Comment: Constitutional monarchy and parliamentary system aren't mutually exclusive. A country can have a parliamentary system but a ceremonial monarch as head of state. I fail to see what the nature of the head of state has to do with whether the semi-parliamentary subtype is widely accepted.

Comment: Why are you scratching your head over what constitutes a semi-parliamentary system? Didn't you read the free article I linked in my question?

Comment: I'm using your own words.  That's a citation of the work you sourced.  You don't seem to define the term, which is problematic because I haven't seen it in any government classification source and doubt it would be widely used one year out from the publishing date to begin with.   The definition also mixes terms as semi-presidential governments split executive powers between Heads of state and Heads of government.

Comment: I did define it (remember I said 'In it, the legislative branch is...'?) But I'll quote the source and hopefully it'll clarify the definition for you: "A semi‐presidential system divides the executive into two equally legitimate parts, only one of which – the prime minister – depends on assembly confidence for its survival in office. Conversely, a semi‐parliamentary system divides the assembly into two equally legitimate parts, only one of which possesses the power to dismiss the prime minister in a no‐confidence vote."

Comment: Again, per definition, this isn't going to be an accepted definition as there already exists a term for a legislature with two houses:  Bicameralism (as opposed by Unicameralism legislatures... which only have one house.  Israel and New Zealand are examples of this system).   The Prime Minister is always the head of the majority party/coalition in the lower house and all Bicameral legislatures have rules that limit what both houses can and cannot do.  Decisions to a leader in the house is usually internal to that house.+

Comment: Semi-Presidential governments do tend to have sub-classes, but these are done based on how the power is divided between the prime minister and the executive.  In Semi-Presidential systems, the President is always head of State (It's the republic counterpart to constitutional monarchies).

Comment: But that is where the issue lies. Every parliamentary system in the world that has a bicameral legislature—aside from Australia, five of Australia's six states and Japan—either have an unelected upper house (hence making it not 'equally legitimate') or, in the case of Italy, make the prime minister accountable to both the upper house and the lower house. That is where the semi-parliamentary subtype comes in, it is applied to systems where both houses are equally legitimate, but only one house has the ability to cast no-confidence votes.

Comment: " Every parliamentary system in the world with a bicameral legislature, aside from Australia"   Um... America doth protest...

Parlimentary system refers to the arrangment of the legislature (should it exist) and I can assure you right now, the Upper House of the United States would like nothing more to have the ability to no confidence vote the Speaker of the House (the U.S. equivalent to a Prime Minister, since their lower house leader is not head of Government).

Comment: What does the US have to do with this? The US isn't a parliamentary system, it's a presidential system. So why are you bringing it up as proof that I was wrong that every *parliamentary system* with a bicameral legislature, aside from those seven exemptions (Australian Commonwealth, five out of six states and Japan) either has an unelected upper house, or has the prime minister accountable to both houses (which is the case only for Italy)?

Comment: Does the U.S. Have a parliamentary body?  Yes.   Ergo it has a parliamentary system because the body has rules about what it can and cannot do.   Parliarmentary system is the rules pertaining to the legislative body's functioning.   Government system pertains to the distribution of authorities in a Government as a whole.  (Presidential systems can be parliamentary systems as the definition is that the Head of Government and the Head of State are the same person, and the Legislature just writes laws.).

Comment: I don't think you understand what a parliamentary system is, as it defines a type of executive-legislative relations. In it, the executive is accountable to the legislature, and can be dismissed by at least one of its chambers by a vote of no confidence. The US doesn't have a parliamentary body, it has a legislative body, however. Parliaments are endowed with the ability to remove the head of government by votes of no confidence; the US Congress does not have that power, so is not a parliament.

Comment: The cited source even provides a quick summary of what a parliamentary system is, "In a parliamentary system the executive emerges from the assembly and its survival depends on the assembly's ongoing confidence." Merriam-Webster even has a definition that supports this, "a system of government having the real executive power vested in a cabinet composed of members of the legislature who are individually and collectively responsible to the legislature." https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/parliamentary%20government.

Comment: @BH2017:  You are aware that the U.S. Congress is currently going through the process of impeaching the President... which is nothing but removing the head of government of the United States (head of state too).

Comment: Impeachment is *not* a vote of no confidence; impeachment is a mechanism of removing them for criminal behaviour. With impeachment you need to prove criminal wrongdoing, while with votes of no confidence that is not necessary. All that is needed for a vote of no confidence is for the members of the legislature to agree that the prime minister is no longer fit to hold their position. It doesn't matter why, in fact members of the legislature could have different opinions on why the prime minister should be removed, all that matters is that they agree in a majority that they're no longer fit.